# Функция exit(), цикл while

Tags: python, ооп

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import os as s
 
class Bmi:
 
    def __init__(self, running=True):
        self.running = running
 
    def logic(self):
        print(Fore.CYAN + '   ====================\nРасчёт ИМТ (Индекс Массы Тела)\n   ====================')
        weight = int(input('Введите ваш вес: '))
        high = int(input('Введите ваш рост: '))
        high = high / 100
        bmi = weight / high**2
        bmi = round(bmi)
        print(f'Ваш Индекс Массы тела: {bmi}')
 
        if bmi <= 16:
            print(Back.RED + Fore.WHITE + '(Ваш ИМТ ненормальный)')
        elif bmi == 16 or bmi <= 18.5:
            print(Back.RED + Fore.WHITE + '(Ваш ИМТ ненормальный)')
        elif bmi == 18.5 or bmi <= 25:
            print(Back.GREEN + Fore.WHITE + '(Ваш ИМТ нормальный)')
        elif bmi == 25 or bmi >= 30:
            print(Back.RED + Fore.WHITE + '(Ваш ИМТ ненормальный)')
        else:
            print(Back.RED + Fore.WHITE + '(Ваш ИМТ ненормальный)')
 
    def run(self):
 
        while self.running:
            again = input(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + '\nНачать заново?: ')
            print(again)
            if again == 'Да' or 'да':
                self.logic()
            elif again == 'Нет' or 'нет':
                s._exit()
 
            s('cls')
 
 
runner = Bmi()
runner.logic()
runner.run()
```

<sup>(https://pastebin.com/md67Lebv - код.)</sup>

Функция exit() не закрывает программу, когда пользователь ввёл 'нет'. Почему?

Comment: Потому что выражение `again == 'Да' or 'да'` состоит из двух частей — `again == 'Да'` и `'да'`, при этом правая часть состоит из одной непустой строки, а непустые строки считаются «истинными», а значит этот if всегда срабатывает и elif никогда не проверяется

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zGfiGq2S вот, сделал, как вы сказали, но всё равно не работает при "нет"

Comment: Так там всё то же самое, выражение `'да'` всегда истинно и elif никогда не проверяется

Comment: там не то же самое, я изменил в цикле while elif на if

Comment: А смысл? Следующий if всё равно не будет проверяться, потому что предыущий if является истинным (потому что выражение `'да'` является истинным) и всегда запускает self.logic

Comment: как мне сделать так, чтобы они оба проверялись?

Comment: Почитайте дубликаты, там есть варианты решения

Comment: Хотя в вашем случае вообще правильнее всего не мудрить, не городить ненужный `or` и просто написать `if again.lower() == 'да':`

Comment: 1. `if again == 'Да' or again == 'да':`. 
2. `elif again == 'Нет' or again == 'нет':`. 
3. `s._exit(1)`.
4. `# ? s('cls')`.

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы значение input() в цикле while не печатались? Начать заново?: нет
нет

Comment: Уберите print, наверное?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FmmL3YXc, если я уберу print(), вопрос вообще не будет печататься, можно подробней?

Comment: Уберите просто `print(again)`